# Jquery dialog box closes when I remove a table row

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, row

I am currently trying to remove a table row from a dialog box within jQuery, but whenever I try to delete the row, the dialog box closes immediately. Currently the PHP page generates the table and rows for the dialog box. Now to note, this code works perfectly fine without the PHP page call, but by adding the PHP aspect, the dialog box fails to stay open and remove the table row.

I'm not too sure how to tackle this as my experience with jQuery is very limited and I haven't been able to find something on the internet with a similar issue. Any pointers and suggestions are welcome. The ultimate goal is to be able to post from the dialog box form to a database and any help would be appreciated.

The code has been simplified so that the mysql query is not being used, but ultimately I want to be able to pass an unordered list of data into the php page to build a dynamic query and allow the user to submit the form thereafter.

Below is the code separated into two files...

1. PHP

```
   <script>
   function showTable(str, elementid, page)
   {
   if (str=="")
     {
     document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML="";
     return;
     } 
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
       document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
     }
   xmlhttp.open("GET",page+"?q="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   }
   </script>

   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: true,
              width: 'auto',
              show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
              },
              hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
              }
            });

            $('span.delete').on('click', function() {  
                            $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000, 
                                function(){ 
                                    // alert($(this).text());
                                    $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();                    
                                });    

                            return false;
                        });


            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
              $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
          });
          </script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type=button id="opener" value="PRESS BUTTON!" onclick="showTable('NOTHING', 'dialog', '2pass.php')">

    <div id="dialog">

    </div>

</body>
```

2. pass.php

```
    <?php           
echo "<form method = 'post'>";
echo "<table border='1' name='testTable'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
";

echo "<tbody>";

      echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' id='Name' value='Name' disabled></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' name='notes'></td>";
          echo '<td><span class="delete"><a href="">Delete</a></span></td>';
      echo "</tr>";

      echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' id='Name' value='Name' disabled></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' name='notes'></td>";
          echo '<td><span class="delete"><a href="">Delete</a></span></td>';
      echo "</tr>";

      echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' id='Name' value='Name' disabled></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' name='notes'></td>";
          echo '<td><span class="delete"><a href="">Delete</a></span></td>';
      echo "</tr>";

echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Firstly, you need to remove the show/hide components of the first function and then create a button instead of using the hyperlink reference. You will then need to set tr with an id.

```
<tr id="row">
```

Then a function in javascript to remove the row when you click the button.

```
   $(document.getElementById(row)).remove();
```

After that you should be all set.

Comment: Good work raw, was just looking over your question. Try this site in the future, nice api reference for jqueryui [jueryui api](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) Instead of "$(document.getElementById(row))" you can also use this version: "$("#row").remove();"

Comment: That is a great resource, I'll definitely check it out as I continue to learn more about jquery. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: You welcome, another thing that is good to practice with is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), also useful for posting working code samples. Good luck man!